# Stack Exchange Stock Exchange Tournament

Tags: king-of-the-hill

## Introduction

Greetings fellow traders, you have just entered the Stack Exchange stock exchange. Here you will compete to earn the money by buying and selling shares (unfortunately, we only have the single market).

## Gameplay

You will need to write a program that buys and sells shares. At the start, the market price is 200, you have $10000 and no shares. Each time you buy or sell a share, the market price goes up or down.

There will be ten games played, each game with fifty rounds. At the end, the person with the highest amount of money wins.

***The first game will start with at least ten entrants***

## Information

Your program will be supplied with three arguments:

```
Your bank balance
Number of shares
Market value
Round number
```

And you can supply one of three commands:

```
Name  | Command
Buy:  | b [no. shares]
Sell: | s [no. shares]
Pass: | p
```

For example, if you were to run the program straight:

```
python testprog.py 10000 0 200 1

b 100
```

I would suggest recording change to see if people are buying or selling shares to prevent a crash.

If you try to spend money you don't have or sell stocks that you don't have, your request will be rejected.

You are allowed to have ONE text file for recording change in stock price.

The program will be run on Ubuntu Linux.

### Controller program:

```
# Orchestration Program

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

class Program:
     money=None
     stocks=None
     command=None

# Define class instances here
programvars = {}
# Program names here
programs = []
leaderboard = {"1": 0,
               "2": 0,
               "3": 0,
               "4": 0,
               "5": 0,
               "6": 0,
               "7": 0,
               "8": 0,
               "9": 0,
               "10": 0}
scores = []

# Programs start in a different order each time
programs = sorted(programs, key=lambda k: random.random())

f = open("stockprice.txt", "r")
f = f.split('|')
stockprice = int(f[0])
roundnum = int(f[1])
f.close()

programsfifty = programs*50

# Initialising variables
for i in programsfifty:
    #try:
    g = open(i + "properties.txt", "r")
    print(i)
    properties = g.read()
    properties = properties.split("|")

    programvars[i].money = int(properties[0])
    programvars[i].stocks = int(properties[1])
    programvars[i].command = str(properties[2])

    g.close()

    #except:
    #    pass

# Main event loop
for j in programs:
    if stockprice < 0:
        stockprice = 0

    # Example: python3 test.py [money] [stocks] [price]
    command = programvars[j].command + ' ' + str(programvars[j].money) + ' ' + str(programvars[j].stocks) + ' ' + str(stockprice) + ' ' + str(roundnum)

    out = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
    out = out.replace('\n', '')
    # If run on Windows
    out = out.replace('\r', '')

    if out == 'p':
        pass

    else:
        action = out.split(' ')

        if action[0] == 'b':
            # Buying shares
            if programvars[j].money - int(action[1])*stockprice > -1:
                     programvars[j].money -= int(action[1])*stockprice
                     programvars[j].stocks += int(action[1])
                     stockprice += int(action[1])

        elif action[0] == 's':
             if programvars[j].stocks - int(action[1]) > -1:
                 # Selling shares
                 programvars[j].money += int(action[1])*stockprice
                 programvars[j].stocks -= int(action[1])
                 stockprice -= int(action[1])

for k in programs:
    # Writing properties to files
    n = open(k + "properties.txt", "w")
    n.write(str(programvars[k].money)+"|"+str(programvars[k].stocks)+"|"+str(programvars[k].command))
    n.flush()
    n.close

    # Add all scores to an array for sorting
    scores.append(programvars[k].money)

scores = sorted(scores, reverse=True)
print(scores)
# Find richest program
for l in programs:
    for m in range(0, len(scores)):
        if programs.index(l) == m:
            leaderboard[programs[m]] = leaderboard.pop(str(m+1))

scorekeys = sorted(leaderboard.keys(), reverse=True)
print(scorekeys)
# Write the leaderboard
s = open("leaderboard"+str(time.localtime()[0])+"-"+str(time.localtime()[1])+"-"+str(time.localtime()[2])+".txt", "w+")

# Some problems with this, but can be worked out manually
for n in scores:
    s.write(str(scores.index(n)+1) + ": " + scorekeys[scores.index(n)] + " " + str(n) + "\n")

s.flush()
s.close()

roundnum += 1

# Write the stockprice
b = open("stockprice.txt", "w")
b.write(str(stockprice) + '|' + str(roundnum))
b.flush()
b.close()
```

**Good luck!**

Comment: *"The scoring system is calculated by multiplying the amount of money you have by the number of shares you have and **dividing that by zero**."*. So my score is always  `+Inf` no matter what I do?

Comment: @Philipp Ahh, that's supposed to be 200

Comment: I don't see any time loop in your program. Is each program called only once? And that in a deterministic order which depends on how you add them to the `programs` array at the top?

Comment: @Martin Büttner Yes, each program is called once. I'll add a random.shuffle() at the start.

Comment: The scoring system makes no sense. Surely the only reasonable way to score is money plus share value?

Comment: @BetaDecay your question has potential but it needs a lot more work before its ready for the site. Please post it on the question sandbox for more feedback: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiv

Comment: May I suggest substituting "traders" into "Greetings fellow businessmen"? Not everyone here is male, and it's more accurate anyway. Traders needn't have a business of their own.

Comment: @MartinBüttner you got it backwards. The last edit followed the suggestion and changed it from "businessmen" -> "traders"

Comment: @Kevin L I was just following suggestion, I see both sides of the argument

Comment: @MartinBüttner It isn't. That was my point, and the question has now been edited. Remember that "substitute into" has opposite directionality to "replace with": the original is replaced by its replacement, but a replacement is substituted into the original.

Comment: Although there are some problems with this challenge, I believe that it is salvageable. How many rounds of trading will be performed as 1 complete game? How many games will be played to determine the winning program?  Once multiple games are played, how would you determine who wins overall?

Comment: @PhiNotPi Fifty rounds (a new decision) a game will be played. There will be ten games. At the end, the person with the most money will win.

Comment: Comments can be deleted, and you can't assume that people will read them anyone. Edit the question to contain all of the necessary information (and as plain text: people shouldn't have to read through all the irrelevant I/O bits of the controller program to figure out how the market works).

Comment: Your example of input `10000 0 200` and output `b 100` suggests that it's possible to spend money you don't have. What's the overdraft limit?

Comment: @Peter Taylor I was thinking of having an overdraft, but instead I set it so that if you try to spend money you don't have, it rejects your request. The same applies to selling stocks.

Comment: Someone please implement the douchebag trader whose only goal is to crash the market!

Comment: Discussion on chat suggests that if the current controller is correctly implementing the hypothetical specification, the player who goes first in the first round should always win.

Comment: @Peter Taylor Hmmm... Would randomising values help?

Comment: May I suggest adding a 4th input to the player programs, the number of rounds already played. Or the current round number.

Comment: @AndoDaan Would that help?

Comment: @BetaDecay Well, I just wrote a random bot, but I would like to nuance him with not being able to spend more than half his balance before the first 25 rounds. And then him acting more frantic in the last 10 or 5 rounds. I could do this with file save option, but it's a hassle.

Comment: @AndoDaan Okay, I'll add it

Comment: Read title as "Stack Exchange *sock* exchange"

Comment: @programmer5000 That would be an awesome challenge :D

Answer (score 3):

## Short-Sighted Seller - Perl

This bot has the simple strategy of maximizing its score at the end of every trading opportunity.  It acts as if every round were the last round.

```
($money,$stocks,$price) = @ARGV;
$value = $money + $stocks * $price;
if($price > 0){
 $optimal = $value / (2 * $price);
}
else{
 $optimal = 9x15 + $stocks; #suitably large number
}
$rounded = int($optimal + 0.5);
$delta = $rounded - $stocks;
if($delta > 0){
 print "b $delta";
}
elsif($delta < 0){
 $delta *= -1;
 print "s $delta";
}
elsif($delta == 0){
 print "p";
}
```

You can run it like so:

```
perl shortsightedseller.plx [money] [stocks] [price]
```